# Python Interpreter Crashes on Import

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1

Running Apple M2 Pro on Ventura 13.4.1 I am unable to use the [fintech](https://pypi.org/project/fintech/) package as the interpereter crashes on import. I have tried installing the package in the default system python install, verious version installed by brew as well as via .pkg files in and outside virtual environments.

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
$ pip install --upgrade pip
[...]
$ pip install fintech
[...]
$ python
Python 3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fintech
[1]    78805 killed     python
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/uA1Lqh9H) is the output of the macos error report.

When running from another install type the binaries and path referenced are to that install:

```
Path:                  /opt/homebrew/*/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
[...]
       0x1022a4000 -        0x1022a7fff org.python.python (3.8.17) <c8c391c2-3bb8-33ff-9007-8b5921539b61> /opt/homebrew/*/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Comment: Well it says `Termination Reason: Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 2 Invalid Page`. The code signature on `_pytransform.dylib` is broken.